# How can I access a web server thats running on an app-logic cloud application?

Tags: tomcat, cloud

I have a tomcat server running on an app-logic cloud application.

I have the IP address and port number of the machine but I don't know how to access the web application running in the cloud.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention I only have the ip address of a virtual switch. Each machine can be reached through a port on the switch. ie using ssh, 127.0.0.1:2222 allows me access a linux box in a terminal window. Is it possible to use a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to know for this is ip address which is mapped to your tomcat. And then default url becomes **ip_address:8080/application**

Cloud/virtual server will have list of public IPs available for you. Number of public IPs available is very small (less than 5) usually. So your tomcat will be bind to either of these IPs if its accessible publicly.

Comment: I only have the ip address of a virtual switch. Each machine can be reached through a port on the switch. ie using ssh, 127.0.0.1:2222 allows me access a linux box in a terminal window. Is it possible to use a browser?